# How can I implement cryptocurrencies payment in my WordPress themes

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on a WordPress theme called "Wordreap" is it a freelance marketplace, The pricing by default with dollars, but I would like to show the pricing within my pages with BNB and other cryptocurrencies, I would like to accept the payment with cryptocurrencies as well.

How can I do that? Do you have any plugins that could help?

The WordPress theme that I'm using: https://themeforest.net/item/workreap-freelance-marketplace-wordpress-theme/23712454#

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best would be to use a plugin like these:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/mycryptocheckout/
https://wordpress.org/plugins/blockonomics-bitcoin-payments/
https://wordpress.org/plugins/triplea-cryptocurrency-payment-gateway-for-woocommerce/

Since Workreap is using woo commerce the plugin above should just be the perfect match for it and blend in easily!

Answer (score 0):

Personally I've been using [CoinPayments](https://www.coinpayments.net/) for years as a crypto payments gateway and their official [coinpayments-payment-gateway-for-woocommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/coinpayments-payment-gateway-for-woocommerce/) plugin

- https://wordpress.org/plugins/coinpayments-payment-gateway-for-woocommerce/

After extensive research, I chose CoinPayments because:

1. They support privacy coins like monero and zcash
2. They develop their own WooCommerce plugin
3. They're Estonian, which is a country that is welcoming of digital security, cryptography, and cryptocurrencies
4. They will work with customers from the US
5. They don't false-positive block legitimate customers that are using privacy browsers (eg Tor Browser) or privacy addons (eg uBlock Origin, Chameleon, etc)
6. They have been around for a long time (since 2013)
7. They're used by [many other companies](https://cryptwerk.com/companies/?f%5B27%5D=99)
8. Their fees are reasonable

Unfortunately, this does not adjust your store's currency to list prices in a specific crypto currency. That's more difficult and may require another plugin.